# Erro ao converter SQL - Datasnap Rest

Tags: delphi, rest, datasnap

Estou com um problema:
Tenho um servidor datasnap/rest, no mesmo tenho o seguinte metodo:

```
Function TServerMethods.getComandoSQL(ASQL: string): TFDJSONDataSets;
begin
  qryComando.Active := False;
  qryComando.SQL.Clear;
  qryComando.SQL.Add(ASQL);
  Result := TFDJSONDataSets.Create;
  TFDJSONDataSetsWriter.ListAdd(Result, qryComando);
end;
```

O método criado pelo próprio delphi no cliente:

```
function TServerMethodsClient.getComandoSQL(ASQL: string; const ARequestFilter: string): TFDJSONDataSets;
begin
  if FgetComandoSQLCommand = nil then
  begin
    FgetComandoSQLCommand := FConnection.CreateCommand;
    FgetComandoSQLCommand.RequestType := 'GET';
    FgetComandoSQLCommand.Text := 'TServerMethods.getComandoSQL';
    FgetComandoSQLCommand.Prepare(TServerMethods_getComandoSQL);
  end;
  FgetComandoSQLCommand.Parameters[0].Value.SetWideString(ASQL);
  FgetComandoSQLCommand.Execute(ARequestFilter);
  if not FgetComandoSQLCommand.Parameters[1].Value.IsNull then
  begin
    FUnMarshal := TDSRestCommand(FgetComandoSQLCommand.Parameters[1].ConnectionHandler).GetJSONUnMarshaler;
    try
      Result := TFDJSONDataSets(FUnMarshal.UnMarshal(FgetComandoSQLCommand.Parameters[1].Value.GetJSONValue(True)));
      if FInstanceOwner then
        FgetComandoSQLCommand.FreeOnExecute(Result);
    finally
      FreeAndNil(FUnMarshal)
    end
  end
  else
    Result := nil;
end;
```

Ao solicitar esse metodo no cliente:

```
var
   dataset: TFDJSONDataSets;
begin
   dataset := DataModule1.ServerMethodsClient.getComandoSQL( _SQL )
   self.AppendData( TFDJSONDataSetsReader.GetListValue(dataset, 0) );
end;
```

Até ai tudo bem, o problema é quando envio um sql do tipo:
select codigo, descricao from tabela where descricao like '%AD%'

No servidor fica:
select codigo, descricao from tabela where descricao like ''�%''

Isso acontece com AD, FA, FE entre outros... se coloca por exemplo %FAZENDA% o resultado é ''�ZENDA%''

Comment: Consegue debuggar para ver em que momento o script fica errado?

Comment: Tentei, nesse ponto:
FgetComandoSQLCommand.Parameters[0].Value.SetWideString(ASQL);
Nao entra no método para ver como esta fazendo o Set...

Comment: Tente utilizar UTF8Encode(_SQL), talvez seja apenas isto...

Comment: Sem sucesso.. mesmo resultado

Comment: Tem algo errado ai, ali onde mandou o ''%AD%' considere enviar entre aspas duplas se  a base de dados permitir, o problema é o ENCODE!

Comment: @MagnoCosta, você envia um SQL para o servidor executar via DataSnap?... não era mais fácil deixar o servidor fazer isso recebendo um código que referencie esse SQL.

Comment: Nao consegui entender até agora o que acontece, o problema esta no conjunto %FA (ou %AD ou %FE, etc) pois ele pode estar em aspas duplas, sem aspas ou qq outro caracter q o problema ocorre, fiz uma gambiarra trocando o % por & e no servidor faço o inverso, por enquanto resolveu..

Comment: @jefferson, tb pensei nisso, vou implementar isso mais tarde.

Comment: @Magno Costa Bom dia.. Estou começando a implementar um servidor datasnap/rest, Fiz pelo wizard do Delphi Tokyo. Eu ate entendi como esse servidor funciona.. Mas pelo que vi ele somente funciona com JSON.. Quando tento enviar um .XML ele da erro dizendo que não conseguiu validar o JSON.  Minha pergunta para ti, que tem mais experiencia do que eu é a seguinte.. Esse tipo de servidor datasnap/rest ele realmente não funciona para .XML?

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque é feito de forma automática um *encode* da sua URL.

Resumindo, para você passar `%FAZENDA%` teria que ser `%25FAZENDA%25`, porque o caractere `%` é representado por `%25`.

Isso não é do Delphi tá... qualquer linguagem vai acontecer isso.